# How can I get parameters in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried both `GET` and `POST` like the below, but `Logger.log()` prints only `undefined`.

```
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  Logger.log(e)

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("MY_URL");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list");

  return getList(sheet);
}

function doPost(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  Logger.log(e)

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("MY_URL");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list");

  return getList(sheet);
}
```

And also tried this:

```
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e.parameter))
  Logger.log(e.parameter)

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("MY_URL");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list");

  return getList(sheet);
}

function doPost(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e.parameter))
  Logger.log(e.parameter)

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("MY_URL");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list");

  return getList(sheet);
}
```

This one says it can't read `parameter` property because `e` is undefined.

I am calling APIs from Postman like this:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/MY_KEY/exec
```

and tried sending params with body(for POST) and Params(for GET).

And the apps script doesn't get any `e`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: e is an event object that is only populated when a function is triggered. doGet() and doPost are called from WebApps, if you try to manually run those funcitons in the Apps Script editor - e will be undefined. Useful reading: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Try this - https://script.gs/how-to-debug-a-web-app-deployed-using-google-apps-script/